# amadeus api hotels getting offers?

Tags: amadeus

i am getting list of hotels with the :

```
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/reference-data/locations/hotels/by-geocode
```

end point
when trying to get offers from the list of hotels with hotelid
like this:

```
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v3/shopping/hotel-offers?hotelIds=WVNYC155,NZNYC425,SCNYC047,NZNYC288,XTNYCBSH&adults=1&checkInDate=2023-04-22
```

it allways return empty array
when trying with the id in the example "MCLONGHM" it works
but not with the ids i get from hotels search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use the test environment that contains limited data comparing to the production one.

If you want to know more about the data collection in test check [here](https://amadeus4dev.github.io/developer-guides/test-data/).